# File progress bar using jquery form and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to implement a progress-bar in my form when uploading a file. i added the jquery form script below

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

and added a this script

```
  <script>

    var main = function(){

        $("#upload").on('submit',function(e)

        {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).ajaxSubmit(
            {
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $("prog").show();
                    $("#prog").attr('value','0');

                },
                uploadProgress:function(event,position,total,percentComplete)
                {
                    $("#prog").attr('value', percentComplete);
                },

                success: function(data){
                    $("#here").html(data);
                }

            })
        })

    };
    $(document).ready(main);
```

Any here is my form

```
            <form method="POST" action="/store" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload">
                @csrf
                <div class="row">   
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                            <input type="text" class="file" title="Name" value="{{old('name')}}" name="name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                        <input type="text" class="file" title="Email" value="{{old('email')}}" name="email" >
                    </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                            <input type="number" class="file" title="Phone" value="{{old('phone')}}" name="phone" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                        <select class="file" title="Country" id="country" value="{{old('country')}}" name="country">
                                <option value="">Select your country</option>
                                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                                <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                                <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                                <option value="Azerbaidjan">Azerbaidjan</option>
                                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                                <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                                <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                                <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                                <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                                <option value="Bosnia-Herzegovina">Bosnia-Herzegovina</option>
                                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                                <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                                <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                                <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                                <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                                <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                                <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                                <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                                <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                                <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                                <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                                <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                                <option value="China">China</option>
                                <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                                <option value="Cocos Islands">Cocos Islands</option>
                                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                                <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                                <option value="Congo, Democratic Republic">Congo, Democratic Republic</option>
                                <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                                <option value="Cote D'Ivoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
                                <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                                <option value="Curacao">Curacao</option>
                                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                                <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                                <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                                <option value="Djibuti">Djibuti</option>
                                <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                                <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                                <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                                <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                                <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                                <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                                <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
                                <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                                <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                                <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                                <option value="France">France</option>
                                <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                                <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                                <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
                                <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                                <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                                <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                                <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                                <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                                <option value="Guinea Bissau">Guinea Bissau</option>
                                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                                <option value="Heard and MC Donald Islands">Heard and MC Donald Islands</option>
                                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                                <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                                <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                                <option value="India">India</option>
                                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                                <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
                                <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                                <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                                <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                                <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                                <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Rep">Korea, Democratic People's Rep</option>
                                <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
                                <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
                                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                                <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
                                <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                                <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                                <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                                <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                                <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                                <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
                                <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                                <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                                <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                                <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                                <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                                <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                                <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                                <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                                <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                                <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                                <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
                                <option value="Moldava">Moldava</option>
                                <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                                <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                                <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                                <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                                <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                                <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                                <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                                <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                                <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                                <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                                <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                                <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                                <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
                                <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                                <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                                <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                                <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                                <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
                                <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                                <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                                <option value="S Georgia and S Sandwich Islands">S Georgia and S Sandwich Islands</option>
                                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                                <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                                <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                                <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                                <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                                <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                                <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                                <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                                <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                                <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                                <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
                                <option value="St Kitts and Nevis">St Kitts and Nevis</option>
                                <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
                                <option value="St Pierre and Miquelon">St Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                                <option value="St Vincent and Grenadines">St Vincent and Grenadines</option>
                                <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                                <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                                <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                                <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                                <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
                                <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                                <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
                                <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                                <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
                                <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                                <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                                <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                                <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                                <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                                <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                                <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                                <option value="US Minor Islands">US Minor Islands</option>
                                <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                                <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                                <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                                <option value="Vatican City">Vatican City</option>
                                <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                                <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                                <option value="Virgin Islands (British)">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
                                <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                                <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                                <option value="Yugoslavia">Yugoslavia</option>
                                <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                                <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                            </select>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Title of video</label>
                            <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                            <input type="text" name="title" title="Title of video" value="{{old('title')}}" class="file" name="video">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Regional Agency</label>
                        <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                        <select class="file" title="Regional Agency" id="state" {{old('agency')}} name="agency">
                                <option value="">Select your regional agency</option>
                                <option>Africa</option>
                                <option>Asia</option>
                                <option>Australia</option>
                                <option>Europe/United Kingdom</option>
                                <option>North America</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Category</label>
                        <sup class="required" title="Required">*</sup>
                        <select class="file" title="Category" id="state" {{old('category')}} name="category">
                                <option value="">Select a category</option>
                                <option value="Traditional Rhythm (Small Band)">Traditional Rhythm (small band)</option>
                                <option value="Traditional Rhythm (Large Band)">Traditional Rhythm (large band)</option>
                                <option value="Voices and Percussion (Small Band)">Voices and Percussion (small band)</option>
                                <option value="Voices and Percussion (Large Band)">Voices and Percussion (large band)</option>
                                <option value="Melodic Percussion (Small Band)">Melodic Percussion (small band)</option>
                                <option value="Melodic Percussion (Large Band)">Melodic Percussion (large band)</option>
                                <option value="Drum Kit Solo">Drum Kit Solo</option>
                                <option value="Drum Line Face Off (Small Band)">Drum Line Face-off (small band)</option>
                                <option value="Drum Line Face Off (Large Band)">Drum Line Face-off (large band)</option>
                                <option value="Innovative and Creative Rhythm (Small Band)">Innovative and Creative Rhythm (small band)</option>
                                <option value="Innovative and Creative Rhythm (Large Band)">Innovative and Creative Rhythm (large band)</option>
                              </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <label style="margin-bottom:-10%;">VIDEO UPLOAD</label><hr>
                    <input type="file" title="Upload a Video" name="video" class="file">
                    <progress max="100" value="0" id="prog" style="display:none;"></progress>
                    <div id="here"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" disabled><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp; SUBMIT APPLICATION</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

Now, it disabled my submit button and when i checked the console, i get the error message 'ajaxSubmit is not a function at HTMLFormElement'. Please what am i doing wrong?

Please, any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe `ajaxSubmit` is a function included in core ajax(at least it wasn't a couple of years ago. add this `<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> ` and it should work

Comment: @Isaac, i added it already but the problem still persist